# create new file listing all text files in a directory with perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to list out all `text` files in a directory using `perl`.  The below does run but the resulting file is empty.  This seems close but maybe it is not what I  need. Thank you :).

**get_list.pl**

```
#!/bin/perl

# create a list of all *.txt files in the current directory
opendir(DIR, ".");
@files = grep(/\..txt$/,readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);

# print all the filenames in our array
foreach $file (@files) {
print "$file\n";
}
```

Comment: What resulting file? Nothing in that code creates a file.

Comment: More importantly - your code simply doesn't work. Did you just slap `use strict;` in there to make it look like you actually had?

Comment: sorry I call the `.pl` in `cygwin` using: `perl ~.get_list.pl > output.txt`

Comment: That's why it's not working then - it's just not working, and generating errors on STDERR.

Comment: Yes, sorry I removed the `get strict` as I was trying different ways writing the code.  However, the output file is still empty. Thank you :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written, your grep is wrong:

```
@files = grep(/\..txt$/,readdir(DIR));
```

In regular expressions - `.` means any character. So you will find a file called

```
fish.mtxt
```

But not a  file called

```
fish.txt
```

Because of that dot.

You probably want to `grep /\.txt/, readdir(DIR)`

But personally, I wouldn't bother, and just use `glob` instead.

```
foreach my $file (glob "*.txt") {
    print $file,"\n";
}
```

Also - turn on `use strict;` `use warnings;`. Consider them mandatory until you know why you want to turn them off. (There are occasions, but you'll know what they are if you ever REALLY NEED to).

Answer (score 2):

You have one excess dot:

```
@files = grep(/\..txt$/,readdir(DIR));
```

should be:

```
@files = grep(/\.txt$/,readdir(DIR));
```